# How to get the classification error of SVM?

Tags: r, classification, svm

I created my SVM model and created the confusion matrix, which doesn't look like the normal confusion matrix I am used to, such as: False Positive,True positive,True negative, False Negative format.

I need to get the classification error. I have looked at several resources and I am still at a loss.

```
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(datasetclass$V1,list=FALSE, p = .80,times=1)
dataTrain <- datasetattributes[ trainIndex,]
dataTest  <- datasetattributes[-trainIndex,]

classTrain <- datasetclass[ trainIndex,]
classTest  <- datasetclass[-trainIndex,]

svm.model <- svm(classTrain ~ ., data = dataTrain, cost = 1)

svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, dataTest)

# confusion matrix
tab <- table(pred = svm.pred, true = classTest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer!
I need to have the 'type' parameter set to "C-classification" when I am building the SVM model:

```
svm.model <- svm(classTrain ~ ., data = dataTrain, cost = 1,type="C-classification")
```

I can then obtain my confusion matrix:

```
tab <- table(pred = svm.pred, true = classTest)
```

And the classification error as:

```
classification_error <- 1- sum(svm.pred == classTest)/length(svm.pred)
```